# Only copy newer files with CopyWebpackPlugin

Tags: webpack

I'm copying lots of files using the `CopyWebpackPlugin`, and I want them to be copied only if the files at the destination are older. The same as was common in grunt / gulp.

```js
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
  patterns: [
    { from: "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", to: "./libs/" },
  ],
}),
```

But the output always shows:

> asset libs/jquery.min.js 87.4 KiB [compared for emit] [from: node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js] [copied]

which implies that it copies it each time.

How do I make it copy only if the destination is missing or the source is newer?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @morpheus05 I think [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12643) and [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#cachetype) will help you. The trick is to use the caching feature.